# Find cell address of value found in range

Tags: excel, google-sheets

tl;dr In Google Sheets/Excel, how do I find the address of a cell with a specified value within a specified range where value may be in any row or column?

My best guess is

```excel
=CELL("address",LOOKUP("My search value", $search:$range))
```

but it doesn't work.  When it finds a value at all, it returns the rightmost column every time, rather than the column of the cell it found.

---

I have a sheet of pretty, formatted tables that represent various concepts.  Each table consists of

```
|                             Title                               |
+------+------+-------+------+------+-------+------+------+-------+
| Sub  | Prop | Name  | Sub  | Prop | Name  | Sub  | Prop | Name  |
+------+------+-------+------+------+-------+------+------+-------+
|   Sub prop  | value |   Sub prop  | value |   Sub prop  | value |
+------+------+-------+------+------+-------+------+------+-------+
| data | data | data  | data | data | data  | data | data | data  |
| data | data | data  | data | data | data  | data | data | data  |
⋮
```

I have 8 such tables of variable height arranged in a grid within the sheet 3 tables wide and 3 tables tall except the last column which has only 2 tables--see image.  These fill the range `C2:AI78`.

[image: Screenshot of arrayed tables]

Now I have a table off to the right consisting in `AK2:AO11` of

```
| Table title   | Table title address   | ... |
+---------------+-----------------------+-----+
| Table 1 Title |                       | ... |
| Table 2 Title |                       | ... |
⋮
| Table 8 Title |                       | ... |
```

[image: Screenshot of table address table]

I want to fill out the `Table title address` column.  (Would it be easier to do this manually for all of 8 values?  Absolutely.  Did I need to in order to write this question?  Yes.  But using static values is not the StackOverflow way, now, is it?)

Based on very limited Excel/Google Sheets experience, I believe I need to use `CELL()` and `LOOKUP()` for this.

```excel
=CELL("address",LOOKUP($AK4, $C$2:$AI$78))
```

This retrieves the wrong value.  For `AL4` (looking for value `Death Wave`), `LOOKUP($AK4, $C$2:$AI$78)` should retrieve cell `C2` but it finds `AI2` instead.

[image: Values retrieved by my attempt at a formula]

```
| Max Levels                                    |
+------------------+---------------+----+--+----+
| UW               | Table Address |    |  |    |
+------------------+---------------+----+--+----+
| Death Wave       | $AI$3         | 3  |  | 15 |
| Poison Swamp     | $AI$30        |    |  |    |
| Smart Missiles   | $AI$56        |    |  |    |
| Black Hole       | #N/A          | 1  |  |    |
| Inner Land Mines | $AI$3         |    |  |    |
| Chain Lightning  | #N/A          |    |  |    |
| Golden Tower     | $AI$3         |    |  |    |
| Chrono Field     | #N/A          | 25 |  |    |
```

The error messages for the `#N/A` columns is

> Did not find value '<Table Title>' in LOOKUP evaluation.

My expected table is

```
| Max Levels                                    |
+------------------+---------------+----+--+----+
| UW               | Table Address |    |  |    |
+------------------+---------------+----+--+----+
| Death Wave       | $C$2          | 3  |  | 15 |
| Poison Swamp     | $C$28         |    |  |    |
| Smart Missiles   | $C$54         |    |  |    |
| Black Hole       | $O$2          | 1  |  |    |
| Inner Land Mines | $O$28         |    |  |    |
| Chain Lightning  | $O$54         |    |  |    |
| Golden Tower     | $AA$2         |    |  |    |
| Chrono Field     | $AA$39        | 25 |  |    |
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(ADDRESS(
 VLOOKUP(A2:A3, SPLIT(FLATTEN(D2:F4&"​"&ROW(D2:F4)),    "​"), 2, ), 
 VLOOKUP(A2:A3, SPLIT(FLATTEN(D2:F4&"​"&COLUMN(D2:F4)), "​"), 2, ), 4))
```

[image]

or if you want to create jump links:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, HYPERLINK("#gid=1273961649&range="&x, x))(ADDRESS(
 VLOOKUP(A2:A3, SPLIT(FLATTEN(D2:F4&"​"&ROW(D2:F4)),    "​"), 2, ), 
 VLOOKUP(A2:A3, SPLIT(FLATTEN(D2:F4&"​"&COLUMN(D2:F4)), "​"), 2, ), 4)))
```

[image]

Comment: And that will work for searches across both columns and rows?

Comment: @dx_over_dt yes, just feed it the right ranges and all is set

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=QUERY(
  FLATTEN(
    ARRAYFORMULA(
      IF(
        C:AI=$AK4, 
        ADDRESS(ROW(C:AI), COLUMN(C:AI)),
        ""
        )
      )
    ), "
    SELECT 
      Col1 
    WHERE 
      Col1<>''
    "
  , 0)
```

Basically, cast all cells in the search range to addresses if they equal the search term. Then flatten that 2D range and filter out non-nulls.